# how to determine if formula satisfies without creating a truth table

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra, satisfiability

$(p \wedge q \wedge r) \wedge (\neg p \vee r)$

So far, what I have got is that $(p \wedge q \wedge r)$ satisfies because if $p$, $q$ and $r = 1$ then $(p \wedge q \wedge r)$ also $= 1$. For $(\neg p \vee r)$ also satisfies because when $p = 0$ and $r = 1$, then $(\neg p \vee r) = 1$.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA When $p$ is true, $(p \wedge q \wedge r)$ is satisfied only if $q$ and $r$ are true too, and then $(\neg p \vee r)$ is satisfied too as $r$ is true.

Comment: And, not "the formula satisfies" -- satisfies *what*? -- bur rather, "the formula *is satisfiable*", by some valuation (assignment of truth values to the variables). That said, your reasoning is correct.

Comment: What you did is the same as considering a truth table, the only difference is that you only considered the relevant rows.

Comment: @Git Gud With this formula, if it's true under any interpretation then so are $p, q$ and $r$, and $r$ implies $\neg p \vee r$ so that adds nothing new. It kinda *is* one row of a truth table, the top or bottom one.

Comment: I understand the question to mean: figure out what conditions the formula imposes on satisfying valuations, using deduction rules, and whether there are any such valuations. But you haven't told us what methods you've learned & are supposed to use instead of truth tables.